# .htaccess redirecionamento de URL

Tags: php

Olá,

Queria saber se tem como eu configurar o .htaccess para quando uma pessoa acessar o site pelo domínio meusite.com ele redireciona para a pasta /site2/ e quem acessar pelo domínio meusite2.com ele redireciona para /site1/, É Por que estou usando um VPS e não quero mexer nas configurações dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?meusite.com$
RewriteRule . site2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?meusite2.com$
RewriteRule . site1 [R=301,L]
```

Quem acessar pelo domínio `(www.)meusite.com` vai ser redirecionado para `meusite.com/site2` e quem acessar por `(www.)meusite2.com` vai ser redirecionado para `meusite2.com/site1`.

Comment: Funcionou obrigado.